# Migrating nodejs jobs to Airflow

Tags: node.js, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am looking at migrating several nodejs jobs to apache airflow.

These jobs log to the standard output.  I am new to Airflow, and have set it up running in docker.  Ideally, we would updated these jobs to use connections provided by airflow, but i'm not sure that will be possible.

We have succeeded in running the job by installing nodejs into the bash operator:

```
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_1',
    bash_command='/usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/airflow/dags/test.js',
    dag=dag)
```

Would this be a good approach?  Or would writing a nodejs operator be a better approach?

I also thought of putting the node code behind an HTTP service which would be my preferred approach, but then we loose the logs.

Any thoughts on how best to architect this in Airflow?

Comment: So three months later and no answer... What approach did you end up going with?

Comment: We didn't decide to move to airflow for now... I am still open to the idea but so far it seems more work than is worth it.  We went with a solution with a scheduler running in Bull (nodejs / redis), that calls jobs via HTTP.

Answer (score 4):

The bash approach is feasible, but it is going to be very hard to maintain the nodejs  dependencies.
I would migrate the code to containers and use [docker_operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html) / KubernetesPodOperator afterwards.